# How To Use AngularJS UI Bootstrap tooltips with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The directive `<div uib-tooltip="hello-world" tooltip-is-open="true">hello world</div>` returns the following error:

`Failed to load template: uib/template/tooltip/tooltip-popup.html`

The site uses both ui-bootstrap.js and ui-bootstrap.tpsl.js from cdnjs.cloudflare.com. If I do not include ui-bootstrap.js the page continues to return an error by saying the module cannot be found.

The main module that initialized Angular is already including ui.bootstrap as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you copy over the bootstrap 3 CSS styles for the tooltip into your bootstrap 4 stylesheet.